# Dell Boomi: Reducing the Amount of Emails

Tags: json, boomi, ipaas

In the image attached, I'm passing 4 JSON documents through. The 'Set Properties' shape in the 2nd branch is setting the email address from the 'supervisor' value in the document.

The email is then populated and sent off for each of the 4 documents.

The trouble is for 3 of the 4 documents, the 'Supervisor' is the same, meaning they get 3 emails. It'd be much more efficient if I could somehow group them into one, so only 2 emails are sent out instead of 4.[image]

I'm looking at caching but I just can't get my head around how to do this. Has anyone else experienced something like this?

Comment: Could use a data process shape with a combine documents step using the supervisor as the combine element.

Comment: You can add a cache that will cache the email id against supervisor after it has sent the email and then for next document, check if the cache already has that same email id stored, if yes, then ignore that particular document.